# How to Install MLModern font?

Tags: fonts

When I enter the following code:

```
\usepackage{mlmodern}
```

I get a message that `mlmodern.sty not found`.
There is no mlmodern.sty found at CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mlmodern

So, how can I install the font?

Comment: it is on ctan: https://mirror.apps.cam.ac.uk/pub/tex-archive/fonts/mlmodern/latex/mlmodern.sty also pre-installed in texlive 2022

Comment: work fine for me in a current miktex and also in texlive 2022.

Comment: There is no mlmodern.sty file in the .zip download. It's not there. There is a zip file at CTAN, a readme, probably +50 plus pfb files, a type one folder, und und und: everything but a *.sty file.

Comment: My TexLive version is 2020, which predates mlmodern. However, it seems wasteful to download 4 gb just to get a font.

Comment: Running `tlmgr update --self --all` followed by `tlmgr install mlmodern` might work for you.

Comment: @user26732 To the contrary, it's wasteful to stick with an outdated TeX distribution.